# Is there a way to install the SSM agent without logging in to EC2 instance in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I have a AWS account with the administrator permissions and I want to install the SSM agent without logging in to an EC2 instance. Is there a way for it?

Comment: can you stop/start instances? If so, you could use user-data to pass something like 
yum install -y https://s3-REGION.amazonaws.com/amazon-ssm-REGION/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm

Comment: @AdilHindistan - that wont work (without first logging in and changing the userdata behavior). AWS Docs: "By default, user data scripts and cloud-init directives run only during the first boot cycle when an EC2 instance is launched." - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

Comment: @MisterSmith you do not have to login to change the userdata behavior. User data is run in phases. The very doc you linked shows how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Having Admin rights to the console does not automatically give you access to the instances. The instances have a KeyPair selected when launched - this KeyPair has a private key that you use to initially log in to an instance. If this still works on your instances depends on how they have been configured and whatever defaults the AMI your servers are based on.

Basically if the instance already exists you will need to login either manually or via script (using SSH or PowerShell) and [perform the manual installation steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-manual-agent-install.html) to setup ssm agent.

NOTE: The KeyPair private key is generated and shown(only once) when the KeyPair is first created, its not possible to get the private key for an existing KeyPair.

If you have a lot of machines to you could use the AWS CLI or API and script retrieving the instance details and executing your script on each of them.

Comment: To be specific, ques is regarding the existing instances. When you say that you will need to login by some means - that's my limitation and the question itself - how to do it since the login credentials of the instance is not there however the admin permission is there for the AWS account. Is there a way for it